# Haskell swap nested list

Tags: list, haskell, swap

I have this function:

```
swap [] = []
swap [a] = [a] 
swap a = last a : (init . tail $ a) ++ [head a]
```

If I use this on a list with lists, it just turns each list around, and not the elements in each list. What am I missing here?

Comment: maybe you want to use `map swap` instead of just `swap` for your list of lists

Comment: oh my, thanks. Didn't expect it to be that simple :)

Comment: What do you mean with *turns around*. Your `swap` function only swaps `head` and `last` of the list.

Answer (score 1):

`swap` takes a list of things, and exchanges its first element for its last. Since there is nothing in there about looking *inside* of those elements at all, it definitely will not modify any of the elements inside of a list.

But if you have a list of things, and you want to perform some modification of each item in the list, there is a function for that already: `map`. And the modification you want to perform is `swap`, so let's see how the types line up.

```
     map :: (  a ->   b) ->   [a] ->   [b]
    swap ::  [a] -> [a]
map swap ::                 [[a]] -> [[a]]
```

So `map swap` takes a list of lists, and swaps each of those sublists, without changing the order of the "larger" list at all.